# How to use variable inside for loop when appealing to dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, ggplot2

I want to plot 6 graphs using for cycle, default.clean dataframe has PAY_1, PAY_2, ..., PAY_6 columns. Unfortunately default.clean$PAY_i doesn't work, [i] and (i) also. How to pass i variable to appeal to different dataframe columns?

```
library(ggplot2)

for (i in 1:6) {
  ggplot(default.clean, aes(default.clean$PAY_i)) + geom_bar(fill = "darkblue") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-2,8,1))
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: `for (i in paste0("PAY_", 1:6)) { ... aes(default.clean[[i]]) ... }`

Comment: I don't have any warnings about this code, but RStudio doesn't plot graphs

Comment: So, I added print(ggplot(...)) and now it works.
But the name of x-axis is default.clean[[i]] instead of default.clean[[PAY_1]]

Comment: Does jogo's suggestion work for you? If not, do edit your question with the output of `dput(default.clean)` to help others understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jogo:

```
    for (i in paste0("PAY_", 1:6)) {
  print(ggplot(default.clean, aes(default.clean[[i]])) + geom_bar(fill = "darkblue") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-2,8,1)))
}
```

This code works.